# how do i query a relationship where variable values are all required?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two tables-> USERS and POSTS- and i want to select all the users who have created a post with 3 or 4 types

This is what i have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE type = "1" ) AND id IN (SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE type = "2" ) AND id IN (SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE type = "3" )
```

But i don't think its the most efficient- the idea is that users are selecting types from a form with html checkboxes then the posts users that have made a post for all the types will be shown

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
    SELECT user.*  
    FROM users,posts p1,posts p2,posts p3
    WHERE (id=p1.user_id and p1.type ="1" 
       and id=p2.user_id and p2.type ="2" 
       and id=p3.user_id and p3.type ="3")
```